Lenovo Thinkpad X270 / Toshiba KXG50ZNV1T02: system freezes under heavy disk I/O under Linux
I have a problem with a Thinkpad X270 that has a Toshiba KXG50ZNV1T02 NVME drive installed.
Whenever my system does heavy disk operations, the laptop completely freezes. Most of the times, it doesn't even respond to REISUB. The actual amount of disk I/O necessary to trigger this is unpredictable: sometimes it's an update weighing 1GB, sometimes it's a 12GB write. Both reads and writes trigger the issue, but it's much more common with writes.
I'm currently running Arch Linux, but the same problem occurred under Fedora 39.
I have already tried to update the disk firmware to AADA4107, which doesn't solve the issue. What could be the problem here?
This is my detailed system info:
$ inxi -Fxxx
System:
  Host: collider Kernel: 6.6.30-1-lts arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 13.2.1 clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.1 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: gnome-shell
    tools: gsd-screensaver-proxy dm: GDM v: 46.0 Distro: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20K5S1GA00 v: ThinkPad X270
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20K5S1GA00 serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: LENOVO_MT_20K5_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X270 uuid: <superuser required>
    UEFI-[Legacy]: LENOVO v: R0IET73W (1.51 ) date: 03/25/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 18.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 18.7/23.5 Wh (79.6%)
    volts: 12.6 min: 11.4 model: LGC 45N1113 type: Li-ion serial: 6057
    status: full cycles: 314
  ID-2: BAT1 charge: 40.5 Wh (98.1%) condition: 41.3/47.5 Wh (86.8%)
    volts: 12.3 min: 10.8 model: LGC 45N1735 type: Li-ion serial: 6962
    status: not charging cycles: 298
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i5-6300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Skylake rev: 3 cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 613 high: 657 min/max: 400/3000 cores: 1: 600 2: 657
    3: 600 4: 598 bogomips: 20004
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1,
    HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1916 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: SunplusIT Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-8:5 chip-ID: 5986:2118 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.13 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: InfoVision Optronics/Kunshan 0x04e3 res: 1366x768
    dpi: 125 size: 277x156mm (10.91x6.14") diag: 318mm (12.5") modes: 1366x768
  API: EGL Message: EGL data requires eglinfo. Check --recommends.
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d70
    class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k6.6.30-1-lts status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Lenovo driver: e1000e v: kernel
    port: N/A bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:156f class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: 54:e1:ad:6c:c3:3a
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24f3 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlan0 state: up mac: 7c:2a:31:fb:ab:30
  IF-ID-1: wwp0s20f0u3i12 state: down mac: 52:71:e7:aa:17:20
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: N/A driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-7:4 chip-ID: 8087:0a2b class-ID: e001
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 4 state: down bt-service: disabled
    rfk-block: hardware: no software: no address: see --recommends
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.84 TiB used: 110.29 GiB (5.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KXG50ZNV1T02 NVMe 1024GB
    size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: 688S11JLT8LQ
    fw-rev: AADA4105 temp: 27.9 C scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
    size: 931.51 GiB type: USB rev: 2.0 spd: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 tech: HDD
    rpm: 5400 serial: S31QJ9CH577741 fw-rev: 2BA3 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 937.62 GiB used: 24.03 GiB (2.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot size: 199.9 MiB used: 154.7 MiB (77.4%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: zram size: 4 GiB used: 256 KiB (0.0%) priority: 100
    dev: /dev/zram0
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C pch: 41.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): fan-1: 0
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.28 GiB used: 2.11 GiB (13.8%)
  Processes: 204 Power: uptime: 1h 29m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: deep
    wakeups: 1 hibernate: platform Init: systemd v: 255 default: graphical
  Packages: pm: pacman pkgs: 843 Compilers: clang: 17.0.6 gcc: 13.2.1
    Shell: Bash v: 5.2.26 running-in: kgx inxi: 3.3.34


Have you updated UEFI as well?
